# How can I specify a "reply-to" address without specifying a database in lotus notes, through Excel VBA?

Tags: vba, excel-2007, lotus-notes

I have the code to send an email through Lotus Notes 7. It works well. From what I've seen there are two methods of doing this, and only one of them requires that you specify a database. I'm using the method that doesn't require that, because multiple people will be using this code, and most of them don't know how to modify or read VB.

What I want to do is set the reply-to portion of the email. I have tried every variation I can think of, and nothing seems to work (different errors for different ways).

Thanks in advance,

Aaron.

```
Sub Email_Atrack_Report(SubjectLine As String, _ 
    AgentOracle As String, TMAddress As String)

    Dim NSession As Object
    Dim NUIWorkSpace As Object
    Dim NDoc As Object
    Dim NUIdoc As Object


    Set NSession = CreateObject("Notes.NotesSession")
    Set NUIWorkSpace = CreateObject("Notes.NotesUIWorkspace")

    Set NDoc = NUIWorkSpace.ComposeDocument("", "", "Memo")
    Set NUIdoc = NUIWorkSpace.CURRENTDOCUMENT

    With NUIdoc
        .FieldSetText "EnterSendTo", AgentOracle & "@Company.com"
        .FieldSetText "EnterCopyTo", TMAddress

        .FieldSetText "Subject", SubjectLine
        .FieldSetText "Body", "**PASTE Atrack HERE**"


        .GotoField ("Body")
        .FINDSTRING "**PASTE Atrack HERE**"
        Sheets("EmailOutput").Range("MessageBody").Copy
        .Paste
        .send
        .Close
    End With

    Set NUIdoc = Nothing
    Set NDoc = Nothing
    Set NUIWorkSpace = Nothing
    Set NSession = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Principal](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21238451) field to specify an address that will show up as the "From" address. I don't believe there is a way to set this via [NotesUIDocument](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.designer.domino.javadoc/javauiapi/com/ibm/notes/java/ui/documents/NotesUIDocument.html), but you should be able to get the mail database using the [NotesDatabase.OpenMail](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_OPENMAIL_METHOD.html) method.

```
Set session = CreateObject("Notes.NotesSession")
Set maildb = session.getDatabase("", "")

Call maildb.OpenMail
If Not maildb.IsOpen Then Call maildb.Open("", "")

Set maildoc = maildb.createdocument

Set body = maildoc.createrichtextitem("body")
Call body.AppendText( Sheets("EmailOutput").Range("MessageBody").Text )

Call maildoc.replaceitemvalue("form", "memo")
Call maildoc.replaceitemvalue("subject", subject)
Call maildoc.replaceitemvalue("principal", "reply-to-this-user")
Call maildoc.send(false,recipient)
```

Comment: This seems to work, BUT...
Using this method, how do I get a copy / paste of cells from excel into the body of my message? I tried the line:
`Call MailDoc.replaceitemvalue("body", Sheets("EmailOutput").Range("MessageBody").Copy)`
 but it still came up empty.

Comment: @Farfromunique: I've updated my answer with an example of `richtextitem.AppendText(text$)`

Comment: I'm searching for this on my own, but on the off-chance that you know right away, I'll ask:
I need to *literally* copy / paste the cells to get them to look the way I want (formatting, hidden rows, etc). How can I modify your code to do that, or is it not possible?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know any simple way to insert clipboard data into a richtextitem without going through the UI. You could try to put `.document.replaceitemvalue("principal","reply-to-user")` in your original code and use that approach instead, but I'm not sure if changes to the back-end document will be honoured by Notes.

Comment: Try this... First create the back-end NotesDocument as above, but don't call the send method.  Set the SendTo item to your recipient list.  Then call maildoc.save().  It will be saved as a draft.  Then use NotesUIWorkspace.EditDocument, passing in the maildoc as the second argument to the EditDocument method.  Then use code from your original to navigate to the body and paste in your spreadsheet data.

Answer (score 1):

There a two ways to solve this, building the document and use the send method, or copy the document to the mail.box.

A good way to start is to read [this blog entry by Jake Howlett](http://www.codestore.net/store.nsf/unid/BLOG-20091022-0419/)

These are the items that can be used in the email:

```
Principal
iNetFrom
DisplaySent
ErrorsTo
ReplyTo
CopyTo
BlindCopyTo
SendTo
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just need to set the "ReplyTo" item on the document, as in:

```
.FieldSetText "ReplyTo", "address@company.com"
```

Comment: Is the replyto field visible? I don't believe NotesUIDocument.FieldSetText can access fields invisible in the UI, but I might be wrong...

Comment: When I try this, I get:
"run-time error '7412':
Notes Error - Cannot Locate field"

Comment: No, it's not visible.  You're going to need to use the methods of the NotesDocument class in order to do this.